# hiding multiple tabs is oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a canvas that contains multiple tabs, and I am writing a trigger that hides some of these tabs when a certain condition is met.

Here is my pl sql code that I used :

```
go_item('homeadmin1.complist');
set_tab_page_property('overview',visible,property_false);
go_item(:addservice);
set_tab_page_property('newservice',visible,property_false);
go_item(:btnaddcomp);
set_tab_page_property('addcompany',visible,property_false);
```

This code compiles well, but when I run the form I get an error about referencing my items. I tried searching for solutions but nothing worked. Note that homeadmin1 is the block name that contains the items, and "overview", "newservice", and "addcompany" are the tabs names that need to be hidden. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What errors exactly do you get? Please, specify their FRM- and/or ORA- codes. A blind guess (as you didn't specify block names in GO_ITEM calls: you can't navigate to an item which is "hidden". So, if you hid OVERVIEW and then try to go to ADDSERVICE item which belongs to a hidden OVERVIEW, well, you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument of method go_item should be defined in quotation marks, as your first one (`go_item('homeadmin1.complist');`):

```
go_item('addservice');
go_item('btnaddcomp');
```

if there are unique items named addservice and btnaddcomp for entire form. Against probability of duplicate occurance of item, it's always good to include block names also whicever block they're at :

```
go_item('block1.addservice');
go_item('block_button.btnaddcomp');
```